# App closed after starting ChooserActivity to share image with other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

On Samsung devices with Android 10 we have the problem, that our app is closed after starting ChooserActivity to share an image created by our app.

There is no exception in the logs or anything else. For the user it looks like that our app just gets closed.

We don't see this behavior on other devices.

But on my Nokia test device with Android 10 there is an entry in the logcat.

```
2020-05-06 15:48:04.033 4509-4543/packagename E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://packagename.provider/cache/image-to-share.jpeg from pid=2753, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:742)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:615)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:606)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:520)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:307)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Followed by a warning

```
2020-05-06 15:48:04.034 2753-5090/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://packagename.provider/cache/image-to-share.jpeg) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
```

I don't know if this could be the reason for samsung devices to just quite our app. On our test devices everything works even though this messages occure in the logs.

Here is the code of how we start the ChooserActivity

```
val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

share.type = "*/*"
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link)

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity!!, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileToShare!!))
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"), REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSER_INTENT)
```

Here is the definition of our file provider in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

And the `file_paths.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Does anybody has this problem on samsung devices too or can tell me how to fix the error we see in our logs so we can test if that will fix the problem on samsung devices?

**Update:** 
We found following exception in the logs.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: android:ui, PID: 26528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://{{ogunsecureurl}}/
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl.uri(HttpUrl.java:357)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:123)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.<init>(RouteSelector.java:63)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:135)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.semCreateWebThumbnail(ChooserActivity.java:3194)
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.semLoadWebMetaData(ChooserActivity.java:3151)
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator.lambda$semLoadUrlIntoView$2$ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator(ChooserActivity.java:593)
        at com.android.internal.app.-$$Lambda$ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator$1JseasSRHRaydwh9UhAQ6FjbwOA.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://{{ogunsecureurl}}/
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2892)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3230)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3141)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3097)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:583)
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl.uri(HttpUrl.java:350)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:123) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.<init>(RouteSelector.java:63) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:135) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30) 
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.semCreateWebThumbnail(ChooserActivity.java:3194) 
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.semLoadWebMetaData(ChooserActivity.java:3151) 
        at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator.lambda$semLoadUrlIntoView$2$ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator(ChooserActivity.java:593) 
        at com.android.internal.app.-$$Lambda$ChooserActivity$ContentPreviewCoordinator$1JseasSRHRaydwh9UhAQ6FjbwOA.run(Unknown Source:12) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Does anybody have an idea what is happening here. The uri authority set is basically just our apps packagename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue with a little workaround. The error occured when i was trying to pass an additional URL to the ChooserActivity like

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://my.domain.com")
```

This causes the `java.net.URISyntaxException` only on Samsung Devices with Android 10, mentioned in my question above. 
Passing a URL like this works.

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.my.domain.com")
```

But i need a URL without www and so i put a space before and after the URL. This works also. Maybe because the Samsung ChooserActivity doesn't try to parse this string as an URL.

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " https://my.domain.com ")
```

This trick works for me. Maybe somebody finds it also useful or has an explanation for me, why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error make the file provider exportable , in the provider component in AndroidManifest.xml file -

```
android:exported="true"
```

try it like that. So your provider will look like -

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: When i set my provider to ```exported="true"``` i get a RuntimeException on app start. ```Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported```

Comment: Weird device related issue, don't have the device also to reproduce and try out..